# Building Regex pattern to accommodate all these words

Tags: regex, split, regexp-replace

I am building a regex code pattern to find extract the below words from the logs.

My current regex code is`[A-Z0-9a-z-]{8,36}`

The following words are getting identified using the above regex code.

```
a60a4c82-82ea-4ff3-ac64-f4450d45e72e
0222bfb3
2110122003513063314
```

Regex code needs to be modified to accommodate/identify the below string using the above regex code.
Any Suggestions/help in modifying current regex query to implement all string in single regex expression will be hight appreciable.

```
      Current string                         Required String

SAR-+96599853915-63aa6d10-2-2Mobile           SAR-+96599853915-63aa6d10-2-2
63AA6CBDMobile                                63AA6CBD
<CSError>                                     CSError
```

The Word "Mobile" is another filed but as it has no space between the srting in the logs, Mobile word gets attached with string that's why I don't want the "Mobile" in the string.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but maybe you want to add a `+` inside the character class? I.e., `[A-Z0-9a-z+-]{8,36}`? Why is the "Mobile" part ignored though? Please [edit] the question and try to explain the rules for what exactly you're trying to match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
(?:(?!Mobile)[A-Z0-9a-z+-]){7,36}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R1ohvI/1).

It matches 7 to 36 occurrences of any ASCII letters, digits, `+` or `-` chars that do not start a `Mobile` char sequence.